# Custom Payment Flow Stripe - CalculateOrderAmount

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

Hi to everybody who may answer.

I'm struggling with Stripe custom payment flow more precisely with the function CalculateOrderAmount() and mostly struggling because of my PHP knowledge.

Basically I retrieve the price of the item from my database and when a customer add it to the cart like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS );

$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );


$sql = 'SELECT *

        FROM card

        where orderRef =' . $_SESSION['orderRef'];

$cards = dbSelectAll( $dbh, $sql );

$price = count( $cards ) * 10;
```

When I put this kind of silly code into the function

```
function CalculateOrderAmount()
{
global $price;

$items = [

    'price' => $price

];

return $items['price'];
}
```

I have an error message: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at client.js:19 because of those lines of code:

```
// retrieve JSON from POST body

$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');

$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);



$paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([

    'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($json_obj->items),

    'currency' => 'eur',

    'payment_method_types' => ['card']

]);
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it is completely wrong, can someone give me a hint on what should I do and did someone have dealt with stripe custom payment flow and have figured it out.

Many thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Your client side error is very likely because you're not returning JSON to the client, so I'd suggest inspecting what value you're actually returning to your client code.